# Run the Zsh first use wizard

Tags: zsh

I made a bad choice when configuring Zsh the first time around, so now I would like to run the configuration wizard (the thing that runs the first time you log in) again. How do I do this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The wizard is provided by the function [`zsh-newuser-install`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#User-Configuration-Functions).

To run it again, make a backup of your `.zshrc` (because there's a small risk that `zsh-newuser-install` will mess up your manual configuration), then run

```
autoload -U zsh-newuser-install
zsh-newuser-install -f
```

Comment: Thanks for this info but this seemed to simply fail silently for me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Not sure why.

Comment: @LukeSheppard Works for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Try running `set -x` first and look at the trace (which may be very long) to see if there are any clues. If you can't figure it out, post a new question with the full trace.

Answer (score 14):

`autoload -Uz zsh-newuser-install; zsh-newuser-install -f`
The wizard is just a function that you can call at any time.