# alternative to bash complete in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, autocomplete

I shifted to zsh from bash recently.

When I run `complete -f _ssh sshrc` it's showing

```
zsh: command not found: complete
```

- What is the alternative to bash `complete` in zsh?
- How to add an alias command to auto completions in zsh shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using the “new completion system” (`compinit`), if not see below.

By default, zsh expands aliases before performing completion, so if `sshrc` is an alias for `ssh` with some extra options, you'll get completion out of the box. But if `sshrc` is a function or script, you need to explain how to complete it.

To make a command use a specific function, use the [`compdef` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef):

```
compdef _ssh sshrc
```

There's an additional difficulty with `_ssh` which you won't run into with most completion functions: it acts differently based on the command name, or more precisely based on the “service name” which by default is the command name. If
`_ssh` doesn't recognize the command name, it doesn't offer any completions.

To make `sshrc` be completed like `ssh`, instruct zsh to do this directly. This not only sets up `sshrc` to be completed with the `_ssh` function, but also declares the service name for `sshrc` to be `ssh` so that `_ssh` works properly.

```
compdef sshrc=ssh
```

Under the hood, this performs

```
_comps[sshrc]=$_comps[ssh]
_services[sshrc]=ssh
```

#### Completion systems in zsh

Zsh has three completion mechanisms: [“old-style” completion with `compctl`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Using-compctl.html), [“new-style” completion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef) (which was introduced in the 1990s, so it's not exactly newfangled), and [a compatibility layer for bash completion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-bashcompinit).

By default, zsh uses the old completion system, for backward compatibility. But anyone who started using zsh after the new completion system became available should use that. The new user wizard offers to add the requisite lines to your configuration file. If you didn't get a chance to run it, or you want to re-run it, see [Run the Zsh first use wizard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108136/run-the-zsh-first-use-wizard), select “Use the new completion system.”, tune settings as desired, and confirm the changes until they're saved.

If you put [`bashcompinit`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-bashcompinit) in your `.zshrc`, it defines a `complete` function that's mostly compatible with bash. The compatibility is not perfect, but it's good enough to run most of the completion functions that people write and distribute with their own programs.

P.S. As a new user of zsh, you may be interested in my [overview of the differences between bash and zsh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh/361957#361957).

Comment: ```compdef _ssh sshrc``` not working at all. but ```compdef _telnet sshrc``` is working.something weird is happening between ssh and sshrc script file.

Comment: @AkhilJ Indeed. See my edited answer. You need `compdef sshrc=ssh`. What I showed was the old-fashioned way which isn't enough, but these days there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It worked. @Gilles 'I am not evil'.